# Access/Filter XML nodes without values

Tags: xml, powershell, filter

Given the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <taskinformation>
        <taskrecord>
            <taskstatus>
               <complete/>
            </taskstatus>
            <tasknumber>000001</tasknumber>
            <taskduration>13</taskduration>
        </taskrecord>
        <taskrecord>
            <taskstatus>
               <pending/>
            </taskstatus>
            <tasknumber>000002</tasknumber>
        </taskrecord>
    </taskinformation>
</doc>
```

I have loaded the data as XML

```
$Testxml = new-object system.XML.XMLDocument
$Testxmlxml = [xml](Get-Content ".\test.xml")
```

How can I access all tasks with status **"pending/"** and **"complete/"** seperately, pipe it, give out the number of tasks that are complete and pending, possibly with total and average amount taskduration for completed tasks?

I tried

```
$taskinformation.taskrecord | where $_.innerXml -Contains *complete*
```

But it did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Edit:**
**Another follow-up question**: why does the following not work?

```
$xml.doc.taskinformation.taskrecord | where-object ($_.taskstatus.innerxml -like "complete")
```

Comment: You should be consistent in variable usage `$Testxml` <=> `$Testxmlxml` <=> `$taskinformation` also when using `$_` in a where it needs to have a script block `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt. This will not only output the counted results, but also the tasks themselves:

```
# I faked loading the xml from file using '$xml = [xml](Get-Content ".\test.xml")'
$xml = [xml]@"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <taskinformation>
        <taskrecord>
            <taskstatus>
               <complete/>
            </taskstatus>
            <tasknumber>000001</tasknumber>
            <taskduration>13</taskduration>
        </taskrecord>
        <taskrecord>
            <taskstatus>
               <complete/>
            </taskstatus>
            <tasknumber>000005</tasknumber>
            <taskduration>124</taskduration>
        </taskrecord>        
        <taskrecord>
            <taskstatus>
               <pending/>
            </taskstatus>
            <tasknumber>000002</tasknumber>
        </taskrecord>
    </taskinformation>
</doc>
"@

$report = "" | Select-Object Pending,Completed,AverageDuration,TotalDuration
$result = @()
$xml.doc.taskinformation.taskrecord | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.taskstatus.innerXml -like '*complete*') {
        #$countComplete++
        $report.Completed++
        $report.TotalDuration += [double]$_.taskduration
        #$totalDuration += [int]$_.taskduration
        $result += [PSCustomObject]@{
            TaskNumber   = $_.tasknumber
            TaskDuration = $_.taskduration
            TaskStatus   = 'Completed'
        }
    }
    elseif ($_.taskstatus.innerXml -like '*pending*') {
        #$countPending++
        $report.Pending++
        $result += [PSCustomObject]@{
            TaskNumber   = $_.tasknumber
            TaskDuration = ''
            TaskStatus   = 'Pending'
        }
    }
}
# outout the results
$result | Sort-Object TaskNumber | Format-Table -AutoSize
if ($report.Completed) {
    $report.AverageDuration = $report.TotalDuration / $report.Completed
}
$report | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

The output of this will be:

> ```
> TaskNumber TaskDuration TaskStatus
> ---------- ------------ ----------
> 000001     13           Completed 
> 000002                  Pending   
> 000005     124          Completed 
>
>
>
> Pending Completed AverageDuration TotalDuration
> ------- --------- --------------- -------------
>       1         2            68,5           137
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Works like a charm. This is exactly what I was looking for. Kind regards.

Comment: Another follow-up: why does $xml.doc.taskinformation.taskrecord | where-object ($_.taskstatus.innerxml -like "complete") not work?

Comment: @stout.johnson That is because `$_.taskstatus.innerxml` returns the whole tag, including the angled brackets like **<complete />** and **<pending />**. Adding the asterikses before and after in the like comparison means that something can preceed or follow the text you are comparing. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/wildcard-characters-used-in-string-comparisons) for this so called 'Wildcard comparison'

Comment: Yeah ok, the asterikses should be there. The formatting of the comments without Code tag somehow "swallowed" my asterikses. But even with asterikses it does not work. `code $xml.doc.taskinformation.taskrecord | where-object ($_.taskstatus.innerxml -like "*complete*") ` does not return values.

Comment: You need to use curly braces for the Where-Object like `$xml.doc.taskinformation.taskrecord |  Where-Object { $_.taskstatus.innerXml -like '*complete*' }`

Comment: Sometimes it is the details : ) Thank you for clarifying it mate. Help is much appreciated. Regards

Comment: @stout.johnson You're welcome! This was easy to overlook.

Comment: Btw, is there a way I can boost your reputation for helping me in this case? I do not seem to be able to upvote your answer, since I am new to stackoverflow. I would like to show my gratitude in any way.

Comment: @stout.johnson You have accepted the answer, so that is more than enough for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

A little XPath will help you.

```
$x = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <taskinformation>
        <taskrecord>
            <taskstatus>
               <complete/>
            </taskstatus>
            <tasknumber>000001</tasknumber>
            <taskduration>13</taskduration>
        </taskrecord>
        <taskrecord>
            <taskstatus>
               <pending/>
            </taskstatus>
            <tasknumber>000002</tasknumber>
        </taskrecord>
        <taskrecord>
            <taskstatus>
               <complete/>
            </taskstatus>
            <tasknumber>000003</tasknumber>
            <taskduration>14</taskduration>
        </taskrecord>
    </taskinformation>
</doc>
'@
($t = $x.SelectNodes('//taskrecord/taskstatus/*[self::complete|self::pending]/../..')) |
  Where-Object { $_.taskstatus.ChildNodes[0].Name -eq 'complete' } |
  ForEach-Object { $_.taskduration } | Measure-Object -Average -Sum |
  Select @{ Name='TotalCount'; Expression={$t.Count} }, Average, Sum |
  Format-Table -AutoSize

TotalCount Average Sum
---------- ------- ---
         3    13,5  27
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this Andrei! Also works very well and let me gain useful Information. Kind regards.